# How to increase the process performance by reducing following codes?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written a program using progress 4GL. The syntax is correct but don't know how to reduce the codes..We are the company working for seats and using progress 4gl..we have one table called shift maintenance which has shift time for every hours.Let explain with an example.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE FistshiftStartHour AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE FistShiftEnddHour AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE SecshiftStartHour AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE SecShiftEnddHour AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

FIND FIRST shift WHERE shift.shiftsequence = 1 NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
ASSIGN
        FistshiftStartHour = shift.starthour
        FistShiftEnddHour = shift.endhour.

FIND FIRST shift WHERE shift.shiftsequence = 2 NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
ASSIGN
        SecshiftStartHour = shift.starthour
        SecShiftEnddHour = shift.endhour.
```

Like this i need to write a query for every shift hours and assign to two variables for 21 shift sequence.Is there any chance for reducing so much queries?(Note-I must to assign start and end time to individual variables).

Comment: Why do they need to be individual variables? If you declared your variables as an array, you could loop through your shifts and assign each sequence to a numbered entry in your array. To have 21 pairs of individually declared variables is a lot of code lines and I don't think you can do anything efficiently to populate them.

Comment: The reason behind is there must be a chance to change the shift hours ..so that i have assigned those shift time table fields directly to variables..Finally whatever they change time for shift which will never affect the queries otherwise each and every time i need to do change the queries without assign to the variables

Comment: @Screwtape Otherwise can you please write a query for looping without variables assign for 21 sequence..couldyou help in this case sir?

Comment: You would start `FOR EACH shift NO-LOCK BY shift.shiftsequence WHERE shift.shiftsequence <= 21:` - look up FOR EACH command in the manual, and see how to create a looping block... https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/for-statement.html

Comment: To increase performance make sure that shift.shiftsequence is in an index!

Comment: Thanks for guidance sir.. Using index database will find records so fastly..I agree your point..

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the shift time with array variable and assign it when doing loop in your table / temp-table:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE sSeq AS INTEGER EXTENT 21 NO-UNDO. /* start hour */
DEFINE VARIABLE eSeq AS INTEGER EXTENT 21 NO-UNDO. /* end hour */

FOR EACH shift WHERE shift.shiftsequence LE 21 NO-LOCK BY shift.shiftsequence:
    sSeq[shift.shiftsequence] = shift.starthour.
    eSeq[shift.shiftsequence] = shift.endhour.
    DISP sSeq[shift.shiftsequence] eSeq[shift.shiftsequence].
END.
```

Comment: Thank you sir...I will implement this method...and revert back to you

Comment: the code you have written is really help me to get all the data at a time  but my concern is need to assign every start and end hour to individual variables..can you help in this case?